# Вывод ответа для каждого из решений

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Как вывести ответы фрагментов вычисления  с 1 по 6?

```
format  PE GUI 4.0  
include 'include\WIN32AX.INC'  
.data  
x   dd 45  
y   dd -12  
z   dd 71  
p   dd 18  
q   dd -51  
k   dd 88  
r   dd -5  
s   dd 101  
beta    dd 75  
gamma   dd 94  
delta   dd - 60  
Q   dd 0  
T   dd 0  
K   dd 0  
a   dd 0

.code  
start:  
;1  
    mov eax,[z]  
    imul [x]  
    imul [y]  
    add eax,100  
    mov ecx,eax  
    mov eax,[x]  
    cdq  
    idiv [y]  
    add eax,ecx  
    add eax,45  
    mov [Q],eax  
;2  
    mov ecx,[k]  
    add ecx,[s]  
    mov eax,[p]  
    add eax,[q]  
    cdq  
    idiv ecx  
    mov ecx,eax  
    mov eax,[r]  
    imul [s]  
    mov ebx,eax  
    mov eax,[p]  
    imul [q]  
    idiv ebx  
    sub ecx,eax  
    mov [T],ecx  
;3  
    mov eax,[gamma]  
    imul [delta]  
    neg eax  
    add eax,[x]  
    mov ecx,eax  
    mov eax,beta
    cdq  
    idiv ecx  
    add eax,1e3h  
    mov [K],eax  
;4      
    mov eax,[x]  
    imul eax  
    mov ecx,eax  
    mov eax,3  
    imul [x]  
    add eax,ecx  
    sub eax,7  
    mov [y],eax  
;5       
    mov ebx,[x]  
    mov eax,[x]  
    imul ebx  
    mov ecx,eax  
    mov eax,13  
    imul ebx  
    sub ecx,ebx  
    add ecx,5  
    test ecx,ecx  
    jns m1  
    neg ecx  
m1: mov eax,ebx  
    imul ebx  
    imul ebx  
    add eax,ecx  
    sub eax,11  
    mov [a],eax

;6       
    mov ebx,[x]  
    mov eax,3  
    imul ebx  
    imul ebx  
    imul ebx  
    imul ebx  
    mov ecx,eax  
    mov eax,12      
    imul ebx  
    imul ebx  
    imul ebx  
    add ecx,eax  
    mov eax,4  
    imul ebx    
    sub ecx,eax  
    add ecx,7  
    jns m2  
    neg ecx  
m2: mov eax,13  
    imul ebx  
    add eax,ecx  
    mov [s],eax  
    invoke ExitProcess,0          ;Выход из программы  
.end start
```

Comment: @viktor-922, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @viktor-922, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

В разделе .data выделяем буфер, куда будем писать строку перед выводом:

```
buf rb 256 ; или buf db dup(?)
```

Там где нужно выводить, например после 1 фрагмента пишем:

```
cinvoke wsprintf, buf, "Q = %d", [Q] ; или eax вместо [Q], т.к. результат все еще находится там
invoke MessageBox, 0, buf, "Результат", MB_OK
```

Comment: cinvoke wsprintf buf, "Q = %d", [Q] ; или eax вместо [Q], т.к. результат все еще находится там
invoke MessageBox 0, buf, "Результат", MB_OK
не компилируется блин пишет  call[MessageBox 0]

Comment: Поправил, нужна была запятая между именем функции и параметрами