# Вывод числа в messagebox на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, вывод, fasm

Требовалось запрограммировать математическую формулу (A+B) / (D*E) - C.
Вот я всё посчитал, но в окне почему-то выводятся байты полученного числа, а не оно само. Как это исправить? Может есть какие-нибудь макросы для вывода числа в messagebox в человеческом виде?

Код на фасме:

```
format PE GUI 5.0
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\win32a.inc'
entry start

section '.data' data readable writeable

Caption db 'Ответ к задаче',0
result dw 0
A dw 1
B dw 2
C dw 3
D dw 4
E dw 5

section '.code' readable executable

start:

; зануляем регистры которыми будем пользоваться
xor EAX, EAX
xor EBX, EBX
xor ECX, ECX

mov AX, [A]
add AX, [B] ; AX = A + B
mov AX, CX ; CX = AX
xor AX, AX
mov AX, [D]
mul [E] ; AX = D * E
mov BX, AX ; BX = D * E
mov CX, AX
div BX ; AX = (A+B)/(D*E)
sub AX, [C] ; AX = (A+B)/(D*E) - C
mov [result], AX

invoke MessageBox,0,result,Caption,MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess,0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL', user32,'USER32.DLL' 
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\API\kernel32.inc'
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\API\user32.inc'
```

upd: результатом работы данной программы будет являться непонятная строка вида "юы(и пустой квадратик лол)"

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вывод ответа для каждого из решений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/86009/Вывод-ответа-для-каждого-из-решений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageBox` должен получать на вход строку, а вы передаете бинарные данные (которые при выводе отображаются как мусор). Для того чтобы преобразовать ваше число в строку можно воспользоваться функцией [`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/ms647550):

```
format PE GUI 5.0
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\win32a.inc'
entry start

section '.data' data readable writeable

Caption db 'Ответ к задаче',0
fmt db "result = %d",0 ; строка форматирования
buf rb 256 ; буфер под строку-результат
result dd 0  ; <-- заменил dw на dd

...

section '.code' readable executable

...

movzx EAX, AX ; расширяем результат до 4 байт
; Если результат может быть отрицательным, замените movzx на movsx
mov [result], eax
cinvoke wsprintf, buf, fmt, [result] ; cinvoke т.к. соглашение cdecl
invoke MessageBox,0,buf,Caption,MB_OK

...
```

---

Отличие от примера в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/86019/1365) в том, что  у вас используется импорт `win32a.inc`, а там - `win32ax.inc`, для разных вариантов этого файла по-разному реализуются макросы `invoke`/`cinvoke`. Если импортировать `win32ax.inc`, то можно писать так:

```
cinvoke wsprintf, buf, "result = %d", [result]
invoke MessageBox, 0, buf, "Результат", MB_OK
```

Но фактически строки будут прописаны не в секции данных, а в секции кода. В итоге в секции кода получится примерно такая каша:

```
push [result]
call lab1 ; так хитрым образом в стек кладется адрес строки
  db "result = %d",0
lab1:
push buf
call [wsprintf]
add esp, 4*3 ; выравнивание стека по соглашению cdecl

push MB_OK
call lab2
  db "Результат",0
lab2:
push buf
push 0
call [MessageBox]
```

Отладчики такой код не очень хорошо понимают (пытаются дизассемблировать сначала код не заходя в `call`, в итоге строка отображается как некое подобие кода).

Comment: На данной строке к сожалению выдаёт ошибку invalid operand
movsx [result], AX

Comment: @GreedWizard, поправил